# Print updated counter on the same line

Tags: python, passwords, counter, md5

I have this code:

```
import hashlib

pass_hash = input("Enter MD5 Hash: ")
wordlist = input("Wordlist name: ")

try:
    pass_file = open(wordlist, 'r')
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File not found.")
    quit()


def main():
    counter = 0
    print(f"List count: {str(counter)} Type: alphanum")

    for word in pass_file:
        encoded_word = word.encode('utf-8')
        digest = hashlib.md5(encoded_word.strip()).hexdigest()

        counter += 1

        if digest == pass_hash:
            print(f"Password found: {word}")
            break
    else:
        print("Password not found")


main()
```

I am trying to print the counter current stage, for example 1 gets replaced by 2 and then by 3 etc on the same line until the password hash gets cracked. Like a loading bar just with numbers iterated so far.

Answer (score 0):

Use string concatenation:

```py
stringToPrint = "List count: " + str(counter) + " Type: alphanum"
print(stringToPrint)
```

Comment: This is the output: 
`List count: 0 Type: alphanum
Password found: PolniyPizdec0211`

Comment: Sorry, I did not see that you wanted it all on one line. To do that, run the same code as in my answer but add "import os" and use "os.system('cls')" to clear the screen/console (if using Windows)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using a carriage return:

```
counter = 0
for word in pass_file:
    sys.stdout.write(f"\rList count: {str(counter)} Type: alphanum")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    counter += 1

    encoded_word = word.encode('utf-8')
    digest = hashlib.md5(encoded_word.strip()).hexdigest()

    if digest == pass_hash:
        print(f"\nPassword found: {word}")
        break
```

You need to flush the stdout stream to ensure that it gets written (normally the output stream will wait for a substantial buffer or a line break (\n) to print out, so you'll need to manually flush.

You also need to add a line break when the password is found, since we don't include one when writing the counter.

Comment: Its just printing the number directly not going from 1 to the 500 for example. I need that "animation".